Cpu cycle count for a C program in mac os on ARM64 CPUs?
I'm trying to record the number of cpu cycles for running a C program on a M1.
I know there are x86 instructions rdtsc and rdtscp that can be used to time intervals within a program.  (In wall-clock equivalent time, not core clock cycles - since the mid 2000s, the TSC frequency is fixed even while the actual CPU frequency varies for power management.  rdpmc is necessary to count actual clock cycles, along with programming the HW performance counters, e.g. via a tool like Linux perf stat which can measure a whole program.)
Is there something similar for AArch64 programs on macOS? Is there a function call that I could use to get the cycle count of a C program in macOS?  Either in actual core clock cycles, or low-overhead high-resolution wall-clock-equivalent timing useful for microbenchmarking.
(Does rdtsc work in x86 programs running through Rosetta 2?  If so, what does it do, and how precise and low-overhead is it?)

Use the arm cpu cycle counter. See my answer: I'm studying embedded and I have a question about NOP()

This was incorrectly closed. Although it uses the word “tool,” the rdtscp it refers to is an instruction, not a third-party tool or library. The question is asking for platform information.

@CraigEstey that answer was definitely wrong for STM32F1 :)

Isn't it missing the most important tag apple-m1?

In the linked post, you can read system register PMCCNTR_EL0 for CPU clock cycles, or CNTVCT_EL0, CNTPCT_EL0 for real time at some fixed frequency in the MHz.
